# Proof of Stake via Trust score

Tags: blockchain, trust

I'm developing a proof of stake blockchain for a private project that does not involve a cryptocurrency. As such, there are no wallets and no tokens that are used for transactions. Nodes verify transactions and should be awarded with trust score for doing so.

I've tried finding an example of this online but Googling usually just returns pages of "What is PoS" articles, can someone assist with pointing me in the direction of an implemented example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use PoS on a private network? Private networks usually use BFT group protocols (Ripple, Hyperledger Fabric) or protocols aimed at crash fault tolerance (CFT protocols - like Raft in Quorum). They are easier to implement and provide fast transaction finalisation.

Comment: So it's actually a Proof of Trust blockchain, which functions similarly to PoS, but nodes stake their trust score to carry out validation as opposed to staking their tokens. This is a private blockchain because it is a project for validating the processes of ICS machines and making sure they are carried out in the correct order.

I'm trying to find an actual example of this being carried out as per the whitepaper described here https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8332496

But currently can't find any